# Cannot define Primary key on typed Table DB2

Tags: types, db2

I have a type on db2 like:

```
create type  tipo_vehiculo as(
    Descripcion varchar(30)
)MODE DB2SQL;
```

and have to create a table with pk, using the oid as pk doesn't work, so I try to create it on the table, but the IBM syntax doesn't work for me...

```
create table JORGEMONGE."tipo_vehiculo_t" of tipo_vehiculo(
    "id_tipo_vehiculo_t"  INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE -2147483648 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 20 ),
    ref is oid user generated
);
```

> An unexpected token "INTEGER" was found following "id_tipo_vehiculo_t".  Expected tokens may include:  "WITH OPTIONS".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.17.30

also tred:

```
create table JORGEMONGE."tipo_vehiculo_t" of tipo_vehiculo(
    "id_tipo_vehiculo_t"  INT WITH OPTIONS NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE -2147483648 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 20 ),
    ref is oid user generated
);
```

but get:

> An unexpected token "options" was found following "ehiculo integer with".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.17.30

Any idea to set a pk on that typed table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know how to set the identity spec on the primary key, but I know how to set the primary key.  You need to make it part of your type.

```
 create type tipo_vehiculo as( Descripcion varchar(30), id_tipo_vehiculo INTEGER ) MODE DB2SQL;

 create table JORGEMONGE."tipo_vehiculo_t" of tipo_vehiculo( ref is oid user generated, "id_tipo_vehiculo_t" WITH OPTIONS NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id_tipo_vehiculo )  );
```

See: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-90

However, I point out that since an oid column is automatically generated for the table anyway (that's what the `ref is oid user generated` part means), it might be better to use that as the primary key.

**Edit:** I've figured out how to do this using the oid.  Assuming you take the advice above and use the object reference as the primary key, it would go like this

```
 create type JORGEMONGE."tipo_vehiculo" as( Descripcion varchar(30) ) MODE DB2SQL;

 create table JORGEMONGE."tipo_vehiculo_t" of JORGEMONGE."tipo_vehiculo"( ref is id_tipo_vehiculo user generated, PRIMARY KEY(id_tipo_vehiculo )  );

 create sequence JORGEMONGE."id_tipo_vehiculo_seq" as ref(JORGEMONGE."tipo_vehiculo_t");

 create trigger JORGEMONGE.gen_id_tipo_vehiculo no cascade before insert on JORGEMONGE."tipo_vehiculo_t" referencing new as new for each row mode db2sql set new.id_tipo_vehiculo = next value for JORGEMONGE.id_tipo_vehiculo_seq;
```

Documentation is here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.structypes.doc/doc/t0006621.html